# How do block rewards work within a pool?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward

Suppose there is pool A with 10,000 miners and another pool B with just 10 miners. There are two miners in the pool A and B each having some mid range hardware with 500H/s (for monero mining its good i believe). If both pools found a block with very low effort luckily. How the reward will be distributed? Will miner on pool B get more reward than pool A ? Or will they get equal reward based on the hashrate?